# Conditional pandas series if float number in different series is between a range

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have a pandas DF series series that looks like so

```
0       0.000720
1       0.002581
2       0.002581
3       0.002581
4       0.002581
          ...
1201    0.015678
1202    0.010720
1203    0.000720
1204    0.000720
1205    0.000720
Name: MetricsUVD, Length: 1206, dtype: float64
```

Suppose I want to add a new column to the DF that will indicate if the values in my series are between a specific range, how can this be achieved? All the options I try don't quite work the way I need it to. I know how to create a conditional column based on a single condition but I don't know how to check if floats are in a specified range as the condition.

In the new column I want to specify if the number in the first column is

- Under 0.05
- Between 0.05 and 0.1
- Between 0.1 - 0.25
- Between 0.25 - 0.5
- Between 0.5 - 1
- Over 1

  What I want to achieve

  ```
  0.000720     Under 0.05
  0.202581     Between 0.1 - 0.25
  0.502581     Between 0.5 - 1
  1.002581     Over 1
             ...
  ```

My current solution is I use openpyxl to manually write a excel formula into an excel sheet

```
# Vlookup for media pool
for i, cellObj in enumerate(sheet['AG'], 1):
    if i > 1: 
        cellObj.value = """=IF(K{0}<=0.05,"under 0.05M impressions",IF(AND(K{0}>0.05,H2<=0.1),"0.05 - 0.1M impressions",IF(AND(K{0}>0.1,K{0}<=0.25),"0.1 - 0.25M impressions",IF(AND(K{0}>0.25,K{0}<=0.5),"0.25 - 0.5M impressons",IF(AND(K{0}>0.5,K{0}<=1),"0.5 - 1M impressions",IF(AND(K{0}>1,K{0}<=10),"over 1M impressions",IF(AND(K{0}>10,K{0}<=50),"over 1M impressions","over 1M impressions")))))))""".format(i)
sheet['AG1'] = 'Media Size Pool'
```

I am looking to do it strictly in pandas/python without going through all those steps with excel. I push all my data to excel in the end, but I don't want to carry out any operations there, I want excel to be my output file only once I have worked with all my data. Surely there is a much easier more elegant way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a data frame like so:

```
>>> df
      values
0   1.652852
1   0.386408
2   1.261985
3   0.927493
4   1.984859
..       ...
95  1.799755
96  0.774886
97  0.671160
98  1.623768
99  1.034185
[100 rows x 1 columns]
```

Define a function:

```
def label(x):
    if x < 0.05:
        return 'Under 0.05'
    if 0.05 <= x < 0.1:
        return 'Between 0.05 - 0.1'
    if 0.1 <= x < 0.25:
        return 'Between 0.1 - 0.25'
    if 0.25 <= x < 0.5:
        return 'Between 0.25 - 0.5'
    if 0.5 <= x <= 1:
        return 'Between 0.5 - 1'
    return 'Over 1'
```

You can add a new column:

```
df['label'] = df['value'].apply(label)
```

You'll have:

```
>>> df
       value               label
0   1.652852              Over 1
1   0.386408  Between 0.25 - 0.5
2   1.261985              Over 1
3   0.927493     Between 0.5 - 1
4   1.984859              Over 1
..       ...                 ...
95  1.799755              Over 1
96  0.774886     Between 0.5 - 1
97  0.671160     Between 0.5 - 1
98  1.623768              Over 1
99  1.034185              Over 1
[100 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you consider using `np.select`

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": np.random.uniform(0, 1.2, 10)})

condList = [df["a"].lt(0.05),
            df["a"].between(0.05, 0.25),
            df["a"].between(0.25, 0.5),
            df["a"].between(0.5, 1),
            df["a"].ge(1)]

choiceList = ["Under 0.05", 
              "Between 0.05 - 0.25", 
              "Between 0.25 - 0.5",
              "Between 0.5 - 1",
              "Over 1"]


df["new_col"] = np.select(condList, choiceList)
```

```sh
          a             new_col
0  0.658576     Between 0.5 - 1
1  0.858227     Between 0.5 - 1
2  0.723316     Between 0.5 - 1
3  0.653860     Between 0.5 - 1
4  0.508386     Between 0.5 - 1
5  0.775073     Between 0.5 - 1
6  0.525105     Between 0.5 - 1
7  1.070128              Over 1
8  1.156395              Over 1
9  0.460130  Between 0.25 - 0.5
```

￼
​